# Password validation for space and character length

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to make a simple password validator to make sure it is exactly 8 characters of any type and that there are no spaces. I am a noob to regex but here is what I have got:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" id="password" pattern="(?!*\s).{8}">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why tho? If you're hashing your password you won't even care if someone's password is an opening paragraph of detective novel

Comment: It's for a school assignment. Otherwise, I wouldn't care.

Comment: `pattern="[^\s]{8}"` - Eight of any character that is not a space.

Comment: Thank you @Ouroborus, your solution fixed my problem. If you post the answer on here then I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern="[^\s]{8}"` - Eight of any character that is not a space.

```
[^       - Negated set. Match any character that is not in the set.
  \s     - Whitespace. Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, linebreaks).
    ]    - End of negated set
     {8} - Quantifier. Match 8 of the previous token.
```

`^` (beginning of string) and `$` (end of string) aren't required in the input pattern as they're implied.

Comment: Or `\S{8}` to match 8 non whitespace characters